# How to get values using @Value annotation before Bean Creation using @Component annotation in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jwt

I am currently trying to learn backend development using Java Spring Boot Framework. And for POC I am building Security Token Service (STS) Server whose role is to generate JWT tokens for valid User Auth Requests.

I stuck in a problem where I am trying to fetch **JWT Secret Key** from **application.yml** file using **@Value** annotation. As hardcoding secrets in the code is considered as bad practice. So I was thinking to inject this secret from application.yml file using @Value annotation and then using this secret key to sign the tokens but I am getting NULL VALUE EXCEPTION here. Below is the code snippet of what I am trying to do

```
@Slf4j
@Data
@Component
public class JwtUtil {

    @Value("${JWT.secret: JWT_SECRET_KEY}")
    public String jwtSecret;
    private Integer expiryTimeInMinutes = 100000;
    private Algorithm tokenSigningAlgo = Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret);

    public String generateJWT(String subject, Map<String, Object> claims) {
        return JWT
                .create()
                .withSubject(subject)
                .withPayload(claims)
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expiryTimeInMinutes * 60 * 1000))
                .sign(tokenSigningAlgo);
    }
}
```

And this is the exception which I am getting

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Secret cannot be null
```

I have stored this **JWT.secret** value inside application.yml.

```
JWT:
  secret: "SECRET_KEY"
  expiryTimeInMinutes: 20
```

From my debugging I got to know that @Value annotation initialises the value of secret after the bean creation of class JwtUtil. Because I tried to log the value of secret after removing the JWT creation logic (which is throwing Null Value Exception) and then it's working fine. I am getting the expected value from the application.yml.

Is there any way by which I can get @Value annotations value before the JwtUtil bean creation? or can you guys suggest me best practices to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Creating a bean happens after calling the constructor of the target class. The constructor of class JwtUtil was called and then was called this part private Algorithm tokenSigningAlgo = Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret); Bean of JwtUtil has not been created yet. One of the ways replace Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret); to init method with PostCostruct annoattion

Answer (score 3):

Creating a bean happens after calling the constructor of the target class.
The constructor of class `JwtUtil` was called and then was called this part `private Algorithm tokenSigningAlgo = Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret);`
Bean of `JwtUtil` has not been created yet.
One of the ways replaces `Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret)` to init method with `PostCostruct` annotation

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing can be solved by adding a constructor, e.g.

```java
@Slf4j
@Data
@Component
public class JwtUtil {
    private static final Integer expiryTimeInMinutes = 100000;
    private Algorithm tokenSigningAlgo;

    JwtUtil(@Value("${JWT.secret: JWT_SECRET_KEY}") String jwtSecret) {
         tokenSigningAlgo = Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret);
    };

    public String generateJWT(String subject, Map<String, Object> claims){
        return JWT
                .create()
                .withSubject(subject)
                .withPayload(claims)
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expiryTimeInMinutes * 60 * 1000))
                .sign(tokenSigningAlgo);
    }
}
```

This change the instantiation flow slightly as it will make sure that the `jwtSecret` constructor param has been assigned the correct value before the `Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret)` method is executed.

Comment: this resolves the issue. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

try @ConfigurationProperties

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oauth2", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class OauthProperties {
    private String jwtSecret;
    private Long jwtExpirationInMs;
}
```

application.yml

```
oauth2:
  jwtSecret: SecretKey
  jwtExpirationInMs: 86400000
```

Inject your configuration class here

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtTokenProvider.class);

    private OauthProperties oauthProperties;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

a good practice would also be to have the `String jwtSecret` injected in the constructor for easier testing like:

```java
public JwtUtil(@Value("${JWT.secret}") String jwtSecret) {
    this.tokenSigningAlgo = Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret);
}
```